# Is Selichos recited in the house of a mourner during shiva on Asara B'Tevet?

Tags: halacha, fast-days, chazzan-prayer-leader, mourning-aveilus, sitting-shiva

Is Selichot said in the house of an avel during shiva on the 10th of Tevet? Does the mourner lead the Selichos?

Comment: Interesting question. If this question is applicable to you, then המקום ינחם אתכם בתוך שאר אבלי ציון וירושלים. And you should [consult your rabbi with the question](/q/9146) rather than rely on what you read on this site. Otherwise, welcome! If you're asking specifically and only about 10 _Teves_ and not other daytime fasts, can you please [edit] to explain why you think it might be different from the others? Also, consider [registering](/users/signup-unregistered) your account, which will [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557) more site features.

Comment: IIRC, the "black" Art Scroll siddur that is used commonly in mourner's homes (it is a special version for *Aveilim* - I think it's "Birkat Yisra'el"?) includes all *Selichot*. To me, this makes sense. The *aveil* does not eliminate the sadness of the public fast day. Tachanun is eliminated for a different reason.

Answer (score 3):

[Nitei Gavriel Aveilus1 95:14](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46539&st=&pgnum=505) brings as follows.

Turei Zahav Yore Deah 384:1, Derisha, and Pri Megadim say that Selichos is recited in the home of a Aveil. Shaalos U'Teshuvos Yehuda Yaaleh Yore Deah 353 says that the Aveil should also say the Selichos.

Aveil Hashitim page 45 - 6, Machtzis Hashekel 131:10, say that although the Aveil says Selichos, the Aveil should not say the Vidui.

On the [next page](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46539&st=&pgnum=506) he mentions that Gesher Hachaim page 204 -4 says  to do an abridged version, and that the Pri Megadim says in one place that the Aveil himself should not say and in another place that the Aveil himself should say.

Based on this I would think that the Aveil would not lead the Selichos, unless the Aveil is saying the complete Selichos.

Answer (score 1):

According to what is stated in [More than a Tear by Yig'al Sigal (2001)](https://books.google.com/books?id=al9nSurm7R0C&pg=PT47&lpg=PT47&dq=halacha%20of%20selichot%20and%20mourners&source=bl&ots=zderTiAafr&sig=kWUap0J069jmcK89WEKaJb3RGbk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihldXn7-_JAhXCFz4KHQjQDJgQ6AEISjAI#v=onepage&q=halacha%20of%20selichot%20and%20mourners&f=false),

Selichot are abridged. Everything is said, except for omitting the section *Zechor Rachemecha* which appears before *Shema Koleinu*. *Shema Koleinu* is said, and the rest, until the end is omitted.

This applies on all fast days where Selichot are said. *Tish'a B'Av* (Some *nuscha'ot* do say Slichot on Tish'a B'av. See [beureihatefilah.com](http://www.beureihatefilah.com)) and the Slichot said around the High Holiday period may have different rules.